# Using Leaflet, how do I target content inside an opened Popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am trying to target newly generated content inside a popup. This works, but it is too broad and would cause problems if I have multiple popups open.

```
marker.on('popupopen', function (e) {
  $('.images-content').hide();
});
```

Ideally I would like to do something like this where it is specifically hiding the `.images-content` that is within the popup that was opened, but the reference to the element is not working and therefore I can't hide the element.

```
marker.on('popupopen', function (e) {
  $(e.popup.getContent()).find('.images-content').hide();
});
```

What am I missing to make it work specifically for the current opened popup?

Here's a JsFiddle with my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/vs506sm5/1/

Comment: Can you provide a JSfiddle for this?

Comment: @snkashis Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/vs506sm5/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just target one of private variables inside the popup, with `$(e.popup._wrapper).find('.images-content').hide();`. I think this achieves what you are looking for.

Comment: This works great, but I feel like the getter methods exist for a reason and we shouldn't have to rely on the inner properties of the popup object.